# How to avoid adding duplicate items in a Combobox in VB?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, duplicates, items

I have a Combobox on my form for the user to select items in a drop-down box, also they are allowed to enter their own input. I need the user to add items to a combobox *without* adding a duplicate item already displayed.

For example: 
the combobox has a list of dog breeds such as (pug, boxer, pitbull). So how do I not allow the user to enter "pug" when they type that into the combobox?

I'm coding in Visual Basic,
Thank You!!!!

Comment: Loop through the combobox.items to see if the value is already in it

Comment: So how would I not allow the user to enter said value, when the value is duplicated I need an exception thrown that stops it from being added.

Comment: providing some of the code being used might help people assist you

Comment: You also might look into the auto complete list with the mode set to Append.  That way if they type "pug" and pug is in the list,  they will get as far as "pu" and the g will already be there.  Also helpful to catch miss spells...

Answer (score 1):

Use the code

```
ComboBox1.items.clear()
```

under your code

Answer (score 0):

i have tried it. This works.

And i am only assuming that u want an *exception* when *duplicated value* is entered. Following is the code and it is in the *Combobox1.Validating* event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.Validating
        For Each item As String In ComboBox1.Items
            If item.ToLower.Contains(ComboBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
                MsgBox("Duplicate value: there's already '" & item & "' in the list. Please select from the list.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Dog Breed")
                ComboBox1.Text = ""
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

For more information about *Validating* event, search for yourself. Thanks!

Comment: @MattC: Ok. No problem.